# JavaScript Switch Statement not matching cases as expected

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am creating a calculator app using HTML, CSS, and JS as my stack. When the user presses an operand, it is stored within the `operand` variable. When the user presses the ENTER button, the equation is solved. By using a switch statement, I want to use the `operand` variable to match a case and do execute the code accordingly.

However, my switch statement is not properly matching my cases properly and I'm not sure why.

```js
// Initializing all variables
const currentDisplay = document.querySelector(".current");
const previousDisplay = document.querySelector(".previous");

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');

const clearButton = document.querySelector(".clear");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector(".delete");
const enterButton = document.querySelector(".enter");
const pointButton = document.querySelector(".point");


let firstNumber;
let secondNumber;
let operand;
let answer;

// Adding event listeners to all buttons
clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearAll);
enterButton.addEventListener('click', enter);

numberButtons.forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        /* 
        Checks if firstNumber is assigned yet.

        If firstNumber & operand is undefined, just assign value of button to firstNumber.

        If firstNumber has a value assigned and the operand is undefined, that means they pressed a number button already, append and reassign to firstNumber.

        Else they have already inputted the firstNumber and an operand. This means expect a second number to begin arithemtic.
        */

        if (isUndefined(firstNumber) && isUndefined(operand)) { 
            firstNumber = button.textContent; 
            currentDisplay.textContent = firstNumber;
        } else if (!isUndefined(firstNumber) && isUndefined(operand)) {
            appendToCurrent(button.textContent);
            firstNumber = currentDisplay.textContent;
        } else if (!isUndefined(secondNumber) && !isUndefined(operand)) {
            appendToCurrent(button.textContent);
            secondNumber = currentDisplay.textContent;
        } else {
            secondNumber = button.textContent;
            currentDisplay.textContent = secondNumber;
        }
}));

operationButtons.forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        /*
        Checks if there is the operand & firstNumber has been assigned yet.

        If both the operand and firstNumber is undefined, then they are trying to do some sort of arithemtic with zero (aka the starting value).

        If the operand is undefined but the firstNumber isn't, that means the user has finished inputting their number and are moving onto an arithmetic operation. 
        */

        if (isUndefined(operand) && !isUndefined(firstNumber)) {
            operand = button.textContent;
            appendToPrevious(button.textContent);
        }

        if (isUndefined(operand) && isUndefined(firstNumber)) {
            operand = button.textContent;
            appendToPrevious(button.textContent);
        }
}));


function appendToCurrent(number) {
    currentDisplay.textContent += number
}

function appendToPrevious(op) {
    /* 
    Takes in a button (which contains the operand) and assigns it to the 'operand' variable. Moves currentDisplay to previousDisplay while appending the operand to it. Afterwards, clear the currentDisplay readying it for new user input.
    */

    previousDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent; 
    previousDisplay.textContent += op;
    clear(currentDisplay);
}

function isUndefined(variable) {
    return variable === undefined;
}

function del() {
    
}

function enter() {
    console.log(operand + (typeof operand));
    switch (operand) {
        case "+":
            console.log("Case: Addition");
            answer = add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
            break;
        case "-":
            console.log("Case: Subtraction");
            subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            break;
        case "/":
            console.log("Case: Division");
            divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            break;
        case "*":
            console.log("Case: Multiplication");
            multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Case: Default");
            previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
            break;
    }
}

function clearAll() {
    currentDisplay.textContent = 0;
    previousDisplay.textContent = ' ';

    firstNumber = undefined;
    secondNumber = undefined;
    operand = undefined;

    console.clear();
}

function clear(display) {
    display.textContent = ' ';
}

function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

function subtract(x, y) {
    return x - y;
}

function multiply(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}

function divide (x, y) {
    return x / y;
}
```

```css
/* #EEC61F */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Fira Code';
}

head {
    display: none;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* Main app */
.app {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.calculator {
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.display {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: right;
    word-break: break-all;

    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

    border: 1.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.current {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.previous {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
    gap: 20px;
}

#button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.zero {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-row-end: 5;
}

.enter {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code?vfquery=fira">
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="display">
                    <div class="previous"></div>
                    <div class="current"> 0 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button id="button" class="clear">
                        <h3> CLEAR </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation>
                        <h3> / </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation>
                        <h3> * </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="delete">
                        <h3> ⌫ </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 7 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 8 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 9 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation="">
                        <h3> - </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 4 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 5 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 6 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation> 
                        <h3> + </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 1 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 2 </h2> 
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 3 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="enter">
                        <h3> ENTER </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="zero" data-number>
                        <h3> 0 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="point">
                        <h3> . </h3>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you have a heading inside of a button? werid weird. Problem. You have whitespace Solution: remove the whitespace. Better yet, use a data attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `trim` operand value to remove empty spaces

```js
// Initializing all variables
const currentDisplay = document.querySelector(".current");
const previousDisplay = document.querySelector(".previous");

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');

const clearButton = document.querySelector(".clear");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector(".delete");
const enterButton = document.querySelector(".enter");
const pointButton = document.querySelector(".point");


let firstNumber;
let secondNumber;
let operand;
let answer;

// Adding event listeners to all buttons
clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearAll);
enterButton.addEventListener('click', enter);

numberButtons.forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        /* 
        Checks if firstNumber is assigned yet.

        If firstNumber & operand is undefined, just assign value of button to firstNumber.

        If firstNumber has a value assigned and the operand is undefined, that means they pressed a number button already, append and reassign to firstNumber.

        Else they have already inputted the firstNumber and an operand. This means expect a second number to begin arithemtic.
        */

        if (isUndefined(firstNumber) && isUndefined(operand)) { 
            firstNumber = button.textContent; 
            currentDisplay.textContent = firstNumber;
        } else if (!isUndefined(firstNumber) && isUndefined(operand)) {
            appendToCurrent(button.textContent);
            firstNumber = currentDisplay.textContent;
        } else if (!isUndefined(secondNumber) && !isUndefined(operand)) {
            appendToCurrent(button.textContent);
            secondNumber = currentDisplay.textContent;
        } else {
            secondNumber = button.textContent;
            currentDisplay.textContent = secondNumber;
        }
}));

operationButtons.forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        /*
        Checks if there is the operand & firstNumber has been assigned yet.

        If both the operand and firstNumber is undefined, then they are trying to do some sort of arithemtic with zero (aka the starting value).

        If the operand is undefined but the firstNumber isn't, that means the user has finished inputting their number and are moving onto an arithmetic operation. 
        */

        if (isUndefined(operand) && !isUndefined(firstNumber)) {
            operand = button.textContent;
            appendToPrevious(button.textContent);
        }

        if (isUndefined(operand) && isUndefined(firstNumber)) {
            operand = button.textContent;
            appendToPrevious(button.textContent);
        }
}));


function appendToCurrent(number) {
    currentDisplay.textContent += number
}

function appendToPrevious(op) {
    /* 
    Takes in a button (which contains the operand) and assigns it to the 'operand' variable. Moves currentDisplay to previousDisplay while appending the operand to it. Afterwards, clear the currentDisplay readying it for new user input.
    */

    previousDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent; 
    previousDisplay.textContent += op;
    clear(currentDisplay);
}

function isUndefined(variable) {
    return variable === undefined;
}

function del() {
    
}

function enter() {
    console.log(operand + (typeof operand));
    switch (operand.trim()) {
        case "+":
            console.log("Case: Addition");
            answer = add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            currentDisplay.textContent = answer;
            break;
        case "-":
            console.log("Case: Subtraction");
            subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            break;
        case "/":
            console.log("Case: Division");
            divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            break;
        case "*":
            console.log("Case: Multiplication");
            multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Case: Default");
            previousDisplay.textContent = firstNumber + operand + secondNumber;
            break;
    }
}

function clearAll() {
    currentDisplay.textContent = 0;
    previousDisplay.textContent = ' ';

    firstNumber = undefined;
    secondNumber = undefined;
    operand = undefined;

    console.clear();
}

function clear(display) {
    display.textContent = ' ';
}

function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

function subtract(x, y) {
    return x - y;
}

function multiply(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}

function divide (x, y) {
    return x / y;
}
```

```css
/* #EEC61F */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Fira Code';
}

head {
    display: none;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* Main app */
.app {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.calculator {
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.display {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: right;
    word-break: break-all;

    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

    border: 1.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.current {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.previous {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
    gap: 20px;
}

#button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.zero {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-row-end: 5;
}

.enter {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code?vfquery=fira">
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="display">
                    <div class="previous"></div>
                    <div class="current"> 0 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button id="button" class="clear">
                        <h3> CLEAR </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation>
                        <h3> / </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation>
                        <h3> * </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="delete">
                        <h3> ⌫ </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 7 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 8 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 9 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation="">
                        <h3> - </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 4 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 5 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 6 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-operation> 
                        <h3> + </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 1 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 2 </h2> 
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" data-number>
                        <h3> 3 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="enter">
                        <h3> ENTER </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="zero" data-number>
                        <h3> 0 </h3>
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" class="point">
                        <h3> . </h3>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why do I have to do that? What happened when I assigned the `operand` variable?

Comment: you have wrapped operation symbol with h3 and spaces (indentations) `<h3> / </h3>`, `textContent` converts this to empty spaces, therefore switch statement doesn't match operand definition. If you remove `h3` and spaces from `button`  `<button id="button" data-operation>/</button>` then it should works without `trim`

Comment: Ahhh, I understand, thank you. Is it a better practice in the future to not put spaces as the content within the element tag?

Comment: I suggest instead of getting data from `textContent` read it from `data-operation` attribute, you can define data attribute with value `<button id="button" data-operation="/">/</button>` then to get this value use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#javascript_access) `operand = button.dataset.operation;`